# Android emulator won't start on Mac OS 10.13

Tags: crash, android-emulator, macos-high-sierra

I just installed Android Studio 3.0.1 on my Mac with OS 10.13.2 but the emulator doesn't start. All I see is some errors in the event log:

```
Emulator: Failed to open vm 4

Emulator: Failed to create HAX VM

Emulator: No accelerator found.

Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument
```

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions work for me. Is there a work around for this problem? Or should I just wait for fix in Android Studio/HAXM/Hypervisor.Framework/Mac OS?

Answer (score 10):

"Hakintosh" user here...

Had the same issue.

My solution was to turn on **Inter Virtualisation Technology** in Bios settings.

Hope it helps for someone!

Comment: Great help! I had the same problem and fixed it in BIOS setting! It is "Intel Virtualisation Technology"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it following these steps:

In Android SDK Manager -> SDKTools uninstall the following:

> Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

Then download the HAXM installer and install it from here: [HAXM Installer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm)

Finally, open

> ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib/advancedFeatures.ini

and change the line 'HVF = off' to 'HVF = on'

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I have downloaded and re-installed HAXM but now I get the following errors when I try to run my app in the emulator:

    Emulator: Failed to open the hax module 
    Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system. 
    Reducing to maximum supported size 0M
    Emulator: Failed to open the hax module
    Emulator: No accelerator found.
    Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Operation not supported by device

Comment: Have you restarted your Mac? If restarting doesn't help, open advancedFeatures.ini again and turn HVF to off to see if it helps.

Comment: The following link has the same problem as you and stated that uninstalling HAXM and Android Emulator and then reinstalling both fixed it. Have a look: 
https://blmte.com/computer-internet-technology/1949099_canand-39-t-start-emulator-emulator-warning-requested-ram-1024m-too-high-for-your-system-reducing-to-maximum-supported-size-0m

Comment: It works! Reinstalling both HAXM and Android Emulator seems to fix the problem. Settings in advancedFeatures.ini seem to have no effect. Also I'm not sure if the manual install of HAXM has something to do with it.

Comment: Still not working, its already set to 'on'.
HYPERV = off
HVF = on
KVM = off
HAXM = off

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by going to SDK Manager > SDK Tools (tab)

 and re-installing:

- Android SDK Build tools
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)